# GIT handling large number of branches

Tags: github, version-control

We are incorporating GIT in our project and now we are using SVN as version control tool. Our SVN project repository contains around 30 active branches and trying to migrate to GIT where in each branch size is 6 GB.

As we know GIT clone command will downloads the files from all branches, in our case its 30*6 = 180 GB. We cannot download 180 GB and work, so what can we do to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

git (as many **source** control tools) is designed to contain mostly text files. It's "diffing" mechanism doesn't work well for binaries and indeed repository size can explode.

As obviously 6GB is not text, I'd suggest reconsidering this choice.

Additionally if your branches are so dissimilar, perhaps you should split them into separate repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, you can remove any binary from your migration (meaning [ignoring any path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15923368/6309) including elements that you can regenerate from the code).

Or, you would need to reference those large elements elsewhere, using [Git-LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/):

> Git Large File Storage (LFS) replaces large files such as audio samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git, while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or GitHub Enterprise.

GitHub supports Git-LFS, since they proposed it in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the help VonC. Even if we move some jars wars and other binaries to some repository and refer through maven. I can reduce around 3 GB in each branch still we are ending up with 30 * 3  = 90 GB. as we need all 30 branches for our development since many teams are working on different branches

Comment: @Akshobhya Are that volume of files needed for *one* project, or do they represent multiple different projects, each with their own history?

Comment: Those files are needed for one project as we are having several modules in our project and each modules are dependent on each other

Comment: @Akshobhya Still, you could export them in their own Git repos, and agregate them in one parent Git repos as submodules: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules